# aiohttp server fails to download file whose size exceed some threshold

Tags: python, http, curl, server, aiohttp

I'm using the following simplified server code that should download the file  `./upgrades/file.bin` (relative to server code location) in response to any POST request from a client.

```
import aiohttp
from aiohttp import web, WSCloseCode
import asyncio
import os

FILE_PATH = "./upgrades/file.bin"
async def http_post_handler(request):
    with open(FILE_PATH, 'rb') as f:
        fs = os.fstat(f.fileno())
        headers = {"Content-Type": 'application/octet-stream',
                   "Content-Disposition": 'attachment; filename="{}"'.format(os.path.basename(FILE_PATH)),
                   "Content-Length": str(fs.st_size)}

        return web.Response(body=f.read(), headers=headers)


def create_runner():
    app = web.Application()
    app.add_routes([
        web.post('/{post:.*}', http_post_handler),
    ])
    return web.AppRunner(app)

async def start_server(host="192.168.1.1", port=44444):
    runner = create_runner()
    await runner.setup()
    site = web.TCPSite(runner, host, port)
    await site.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(start_server())
    loop.run_forever()
```

and on client side I invoke the POST request :

`curl -X POST "http://192.168.1.1:44444/post/upgrade" --output /tmp/121`

--> once where the file size is above the limit. in this case the operation halt for a long time, and eventually download a corrupted file (the file contents include some of the http response headers, and it looks like the file last 100 or so bytes move backwards to the beginning of the target file)

`dd if=original of=file.bin bs=1 count=65840`

--> and another before that limit. in this case the operation success promptly

`dd if=original of=file.bin bs=1 count=65839`

I also have noticed that if the client will run on the same machine as the server. and the server will listen to address 0.0.0.0, and client connect to loopback address, the problem wouldn't occur and both actions will terminate successfully in an instant.

Perhaps it's the file size exceed threshold of http message (64k) ? but i'd expect that even in this case, the file will be split to chunks and will be able to download.

Any idea how to fix the server code ?

thanks !